# JQuery Datatable not working in IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have configured jQuery Datatables server side processing with my asp.net application. It is working on local host perfectly. But not working after hosting in IIS. By looking at the Firebug it seems that error is due to the way i have set the path(to GenericHandler File). Im not sure.

Project Structure

`eKnittingSimple(root)->GenericHandlers(folder)->StylesDataHandler.ashx(GenericHandler)`

The way i have set the path in aspx

`sAjaxSource: '/GenericHandlers/StylesDataHandler.ashx'`

The error i am getting in firebug after hosting in IIS

`"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://192.168.194.182/GenericHandlers/StylesDataHandler.ashx?sEcho=1&iColumns=7&sColumns=%2C%2C%2C%2C%2C%2C&iDisplayStart=0&iDisplayLength=5&mDataProp_0=StyleId&sSearch_0=&bRegex_0=false&bSearchable_0=true&bSortable_0=true&mDataProp_1=StyleCode&sSearch_1=&bRegex_1=false&bSearchable_1=true&bSortable_1=true&mDataProp_2=StyleName&sSearch_2=&bRegex_2=false&bSearchable_2=true&bSortable_2=true&mDataProp_3=GarmentTypeName&sSearch_3=&bRegex_3=false&bSearchable_3=true&bSortable_3=true&mDataProp_4=BuyerName&sSearch_4=&bRegex_4=false&bSearchable_4=true&bSortable_4=true&mDataProp_5=SeasonName&sSearch_5=&bRegex_5=false&bSearchable_5=true&bSortable_5=true&mDataProp_6=&sSearch_6=&bRegex_6=false&bSearchable_6=true&bSortable_6=true&sSearch=&bRegex=false&iSortCol_0=0&sSortDir_0=asc&iSortingCols=1&_=1463633008979"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably due to the fact `address` is root based and in IIS site is hosted in a "/" subfolder. Try to modify the address as below:

```
sAjaxSource: 'GenericHandlers/StylesDataHandler.ashx'
```

i.e.: Remove the leading "/" so the call will be relative to your page location.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!. Yes it worked but i had to move the `GenericHandlers` folder to a different location. Before the move when i applied your path it gave me the error ` NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://192.168.194.182/eKnitting/WebForms/InquiryOrder/GenericHandlers/StylesDataHandler.ashx` So i created the folder like this in the project  `eKnittingSimple->WebForms->InquiryOrder->GenericHandlers(newly created)->StylesDataHandler.ashx` and then i applied your suggested path and it worked. Could you please explain me why the suggested path didn't work in previous scenario?